# JS/HTML - onresize doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I wanted to add the `resize` event to an element (I know you can't add `resize` to a specific element, but it would be fine if the JS-function would be triggered on a resize of any kind - not the specific element).

I was thinking about this:

```
<div onresize="wrapperResize();"></div>
```

This somehow doesn't work (Safari user here). This however works:

```
<div onclick="wrapperResize();"></div>
```

Currently `wrapperResize()` only holds a simple `console.log()`. What could I do about this?

PS: [This](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/resize.html) works great (traditional checked), what do I even do different?

EXTRA: The `div` has a fixed height and `33%` of the body element wide. Even though the event should fire, when the *window* is resized I thought this may be the cause.

Comment: there is no native "resize" event because elements don't resize natively. if your stuff is resizable you must be using a js plugin, in which case you should consult the docs for said plugin.

Comment: What is [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onresize.asp) then?

Comment: Supported HTML tags: <body>. Did you try to add it to body instead of your div?

Comment: oh cool, didn't know about that new feature. according to your w3schools page it fires when the page is resized, not the element itself, so it doesn't really make sense to put the attribute on some arbitrary elemnt, do it with js like in the answer or put it on the body tag.

Comment: @SerhiyChupryk ... I'm stupid. Thank you really much. This works, it would be good to have it on the `div` though. Are there good alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should set `onresize` handler on window and do it in javascript,  not inline html.. Like so

```
window.onresize = yourFunction
```

Comment: I'll try, wait a second.

Comment: Sure, I already wanted to, but had to wait for a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot attach a `onresize` event on a `<div>` container. It is only available for `window` for most of the browsers.